# Excel: =IF(ISBLANK with Dynamic Data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a series of data in columns that is populated by fetching data from another tab.  For simplicity we will say Columns A,B and C.  lets stipulate that column 'A' has 5 entries, 'B' has 3 and 'C' has 1.  I have another tab, lets call it 'results' with a single column that I want all the entries (in order) from A, B and C.

1. A1
2. A2
3. A3
4. A4
5. A5
6. B1
7. B2
8. B3
9. C1

The challenge can be that the number of entries per column is dynamic.  'A' and 'B' may not have any entries while 'C' has many, or any combination thereof.

I initially thought to use an '=if isblank' formula in 'results' to do this, but quickly realized this will not work.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(CELL("contents",DATA!A1)),CELL("contents",DATA!B1),CELL("contents",DATA!A1))`
```

This of course returns the results for 'A' but since I dont know how many entries are in each A,B,C columns, I cant just copy the formula down.

Am I just going about this all wrong? If a suitable formula isn't available, I'd settle for a VBA script to get the job done.

Comment: Probably `TOCOL()` or `FILTER()` function you need.

Comment: Thanks Jonrsharpe.  TCOL seems to do what I need, with the exception that it counts blanks because the cells contain a formula.  I guess need to look at incorporating CELL("contents" into the TCOL function.  Otherwise, I guess a quick filter on the TCOL result gets the job done. 

Thanks for the input though, TCOL was a new one on me!

Comment: No, you need to use `TOCOL()` in this way. `=TOCOL(A:B,1)` the second parameter `1` ensure to get rid of empty rows.

Comment: Ah, however it is not getting rid of 'seemingly' empty rows, because A:B all contain formula that TCOL is treating as non empty.

Comment: One way : `=TOCOL(IFS(A:B<>"",A:B),3)`

Comment: This should be faster (and by columns): `=LET(c,TOCOL(A:C,3,TRUE),FILTER(c,c<>""))`

Comment: Mayukh, not 100% resolved.  Again, I believe is related to the cells A:C displaying results from a formula. 

So far my closest solution is on a column with this formula:
=IF(LEN(CELL("contents",A1)>1),CELL("contents",A1),)
then apply a 'sort and filter' and select everything but the blanks.

Not as graceful or automatic, but gets the job done.

Comment: bad link (404 error) =/

Comment: Mayukh,

Yes, with direct data works fine.  
See https://imgur.com/a/vXWUFKz

A,B and C have direct data.  E,F,G use a formula to display the results from A B and C
I uses your formula and produces error

Comment: are those formulas returning as arrays ?

Comment: E F and G is using this formula copied down:
IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))=LEN(A1),LEFT(A1,7),"")

Comment: How about this one? `=TOCOL(FILTER(A:C,MMULT(N(A:C<>""),{1;1;1})),1,3)` i see what you have done, why are you applying the formula for the whole range for col E F G excel will slow down

Comment: The maximum number of possible entries that could be entered per columns A,B and C is 256.  That number is dynamic, could be none or could be 256 or any number in between.  I only copy the formula down to 256.  I could use your formula, but it would need to be on E:G 

=TOCOL(FILTER(E:G,MMULT(N(E:G<>""),{1;1;1})),1,3)

This still returns 'blanks' because the cells contain formula 
RESULT:

1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
.
.
1
2
.
.
.

Comment: Here again [see](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AlEkksoPTc2ck3cWuyZr-ULHfFih?e=stGiJI)

Comment: Hahaha!  YES!!!!
Use NA to mark empty cells.  Love it! 
IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))=LEN(A1),LEFT(A1,7),NA())

then your TCOL formula works just right!

Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Yeah. Might make it easier to follow for someone else.

Comment: Since you are using `MS365` you can amend your formula instead of using `VOLATILE` function `INDIRECT()` use `SEQUENCE()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula should work, but before that the existing formulas in the Columns `A`, `B` and `C` needs to return `#N/A` when it returns nothing.

Therefore, the existing formulas needs to be amended as:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))=LEN(A1),LEFT(A1,7),NA())
```

---

And then apply `TOCOL()` --> in the second param, `2` means to ignore errors but we can use `3` as well.

```
=TOCOL(IFS(E:G<>"",E:G),3,3)
```

---

[image]

---

Also, the existing formula can be made further shorter using `SEQUENCE()` function:

```
=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))=LEN(A1),LEFT(A1,7),NA())
```

---

It is better to use `SEQUENCE()` function instead of `Volatile` `INDIRECT()` function, because volatile functions makes excel work slower as well as it will always recalculate if there is a change in any open workbook, also note it is single-threaded.

---

Comment: Oh neat...learned a lot on this one.  Thanks for takin the time.

Comment: @jhayton glad to know, thank you very much for your patience as well!!